# How to exceed manufacturer supported memory RAM

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, ddr2

I have an intel pentium D 940 processor. I have tried ms config then check the maximum memory changed it to maximum, 6k+mb but when i click apply after restart it goes back again to 1025mb. I unchecked itstill its 3.25 usable, any helpful tips? and im running on windows 7 ultimate 64 bit. and it says in crucial.com that my limit is 4k+mb how to exceed?

my mother board is model is

EX333AA-ABA m7590n

Comment: You would need to provide more information for someone to be able to help.  For example, the make and model of your computer and the RAM configuration.  However, if I understand your question, it sounds like a motherboard limitation.  You would not be able to circumvent that by changing a setting in ms config.  If I'm misunderstanding, see if you can clarify your question.

Comment: @fixer1234 how to find ram configuration sir?

Comment: How many sockets, how many RAM modules in them?  Can you identify the modules (memory size, other identifying information)?  What did crucial.com say about the requirements and limits?  I did a search on that model number and what comes back is an HP Pavilion that shipped with Win XP Media Center and 2 GB DDR2 RAM.  Is that the right one?

Comment: In the detailed listing for that computer, it says there are 4 slots and the maximum supported memory is 4 GB.  If that's the case, there is no practical way to exceed 4 GB.

Comment: @fixer1234 crucial.com says 



Maximum memory: 4096MB
Slots: 4 (2 banks of 2)
*Not to exceed manufacturer supported memory.

first slot is 2gb 
second third and fourth is 1gb each.
 *i thought it was 6gb all in all *

a have a high reserved memory like 1.7k mb


my mother board is EX333AA-ABA m7590n

Comment: @fixer1234 oh, so even if i update my bios it still wont exceed sir?

Comment: It's not clear that you can use a 2 GB DIMM.  It looks like the computer shipped with 2 x 1 GB.  If you added the 2 GB, it looks like the computer is using 1 GB of it (which would not be a reliable way to achieve 1 GB).  The limitation is in the motherboard design.  The BIOS just recognizes what is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That motherboard is limited to 4 x 1 GB DIMMs.  That is a design limitation.  There is not a practical way to expand that and there are no settings (BIOS or MS Config), that can over-ride or circumvent that.  This is a fairly old computer that was powerful in its day but pretty slow by today's standards.  Even if there was a way to expand the RAM, the performance would be limited by the other components.